# Using LINQ with Open XML (Excel)

Tags: c#, linq, openxml

I have an excel sheet and I am processing it by using **Open XML SDK 2.0**. The scenario is, There is a column which contains date in my excel sheet. I need to get the maximum and minimum date from that column.

I can do this by looping and reaching to that cell, doing comparisons and finding desired answer.

But due to **optimality** I want to do this by using **LINQ** to get Minimum and maximum dates.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, then how?

Comment: I am simply looping in each row and each cell and reaching to that cell that contains the date and comparing with the last saved dates for min and max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to all**

I have used like this

```
IEnumerable<Cell> cells = workSheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c => string.Compare(GetColumnName(c.CellReference.Value), strIndex, false) == 0).OrderBy(c => c.CellValue.Text);
```

And getting min and max values like this

```
int cellCount = cells.Count();
Cell MaxCell = cells.ToArray()[0];
Cell MinCell = cells.ToArray()[cellCount - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see how to get IEnumerable of all cells from column there:[Read excel sheet data in columns using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715690/read-excel-sheet-data-in-columns-using-openxml), and use Max() on it.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to take a look at the LINQ `Min()` and `Max()` functions.  If you need to return the entire `Cell` object, you can use `OrderByDescending()`.

Comment: Hi.. Can you please tell me in detail.. I am not getting

Answer (score 0):

You could read this post [Open XML SDK and LINQ to XML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/07/09/open-xml-sdk-and-linq-to-xml.aspx) by Eric White (Eric wrote a lot of posts about OpenXML and LINQ). And then you will be able to query your Excel file data with LINQ. You might want to see the spreadsheet objects structure in [The Open XML SDK Productivity Tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSMLR19JWA), which can generate the source code for you. You could use this code to understand how to programmatically access the data you need.